# Is it possible to mutate a state prop in a module using another’s module mutator in vuejs2?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Lets say we have something like this:

```
const moduleA = {
  state: { name: 'Cristian' },
  namespaced: true,
}

const moduleB = {
  state: { color: 'red' },
  namespaced: true,
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { user: null, },
  modules: {
    a: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  },
  mutations: {
    setPropValue(state, payload) {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(payload)) {
        state[key] = value;
      }
    },
  },
})
```

On my vue instance I have a firebase observer to get when the user logs in/out and change state accordingly. So what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
const payload = {
  module: 'root',
  payload: { user, },
}

this.$store.commit('setPropValue', {payload});
```

then for another module:

```
const payload = {
  module: 'a',
  payload: { name: 'Alexander', },
}
```

and run the same logic, but with different load and change the props from module a:

```
this.$store.commit('setPropValue', {payload});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of committing to the mutation directly, consider using an action

```
this.$store.dispatch('setPropValue', { user });
```

Then in vuex, your action

```
actions: {
  setPropValue({ commit }, { user }) {
    commit("a/setName", user.name);
    commit("b/setColor", user.favoriteColor);
  }
}
```

Each module will need its own 'local' mutation in order to modify that modules state.

See https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html for details

Comment: But I still need to create 2 mutation functions in those modules, I was thinking of using one mutation function logic from one module, pass it a config object and mutate others modules state depending on the conf object, without the need to duplicate the logic of that mutation function in other modules..

Comment: The modules mutations can be super simple... module A) setName: (state, name) => state.name = name

Comment: Yes I know :), I've updated my initial Q, I think you got me wrong, it all reduces to: use only one mutator logic from a module to change the other modules state without the need to duplicate the logic in them.

Comment: I see... I mean what you want to do is possible: https://jsfiddle.net/tnepeod3/ Not sure I like something like that though -_-

Comment: That's my thought, mby if we can pass an array we can get the module name,state prop name and value dynamically and pass them to a single line? something like rootState.[dyn mod name].[dyn state prop] = [dyn value]

Comment: That's how i have it right now but, after 4 modules....it looks like this in my model http://imgur.com/a/Q9qfi